# del with cmd a file from dir if it exists in another dir

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

i want to delete files that exist in dir A if they exists in dir B
something like this

```
A\dir1\fileA
A\dir1\fileB
A\dir2\fileC
A\dir3\fileD


B\dir9\fileA
B\dir8\fileF
B\dir3\fileB
B\dirWhatEver\fileZ
```

i want fileA , fileB to be deleted from dir A without deleting any subdir just the file using Command-line or batch file from windows

Edit: Can i get the result from dir /b /s from one dir and compare it with another dir is result and delete what is match from first result

Edit: `for %F in (A\"*") do @if exist "B\%F" del "%F"` didn't work i think it does not look in B subdirs it just look for B

and A dir and B dir have spaces in it

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). It says (amongst other things)  "**Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!**"

Comment: "i want ppl to tell me how to do it to get more knowledge how things works and what is the best approach my goal". Questions seeking product, service, or **learning material recommendations** are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

For your particular goal, you must just want to find a dedicated tool.  I remember seeing a program called YAFF (Yet Another File Finder), which had that name because there were other ones out there.  (This is my main short on-topic complete answer.  The rest of my answer is discussion of some alternatives.)

If you don't like YAFF, search for either "file finder" or "deduplication"/"deduplicate", or "find duplicate", and I think you'll find many results.  (It's kind of a fun thing for programmers to create after they start to learn recursion and file handling, so quite a few people have written tools for such a thing.)  De-duplication is also a feature that lots of people are talking about for filesystem features and backup software, so you may get quite a few discussions about those topics which you're not asking about, but also find what you are trying to do.

I have done something extremely similar to this, where I could do something with a file (including deleting it, or using an "echo" command and writing to a text file, or whatever I wanted) to A\dir1\fileA if B\dir1\fileA existed.  To do so, I used JP Software's command prompts (typically 4DOS back in the day, but the modern day equivalent would be TCC/LE), with internal variables to refer to the full filename (%@full) and substrings/etc.  I never stored the source code because I just got good at taking three minutes to re-create it whenever I needed to.  Something like: global /i for %%X in (*.*) if exist DIRB\%@substr[something%@full[.]] echo DIRB\%@substr[something%@full[.]] do-whatever (or @instr)...  The "something" would need to be customized based on how long the common paths were.

Supporting potentially different subdirectories may be possible, by using "for" to descend into any subdirectory.  If the subdirectories are different names, you may need to use GLOBAL/i, which is an internal command of JP Software's products, and which did not have an equivalent command built into CMD the last time I checked (multiple operating systems ago).  I'm sure something could be crafted (maybe: global, if exist, then write to a temp file in a known name; then if that temp file exists, delete.)